# using sed with local variables that have /

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I'm trying to make the sed command replace these:

```
CURRENT_TOMCAT=/opt/tomcat/lib
NEW_TOMCAT=/usr/tomcat/lib
sed -i "s/$CURRENT_TOMCAT/$NEW_TOMCAT/" tomcat.env
```

I've tried a bunch of combinations with no success, sometimes getting the unknown option to `s' error, sometimes getting no errors, but no changes are made

The line I that needs to be change looks like this:

```
TOMCAT_LIB=/opt/tomcat/lib; export TOMCAT_LIB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the delimiter to another one not contained in your strings. For example, `#`:

```
CURRENT_TOMCAT=/opt/tomcat/lib
NEW_TOMCAT=/usr/tomcat/lib
sed -i "s#$CURRENT_TOMCAT#$NEW_TOMCAT#" tomcat.env 
         ^               ^           ^
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello/how are you?

$ old="hello/how"
$ new="bye/how"

$ sed "s/$old/$new/" a
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unknown option to `s' <---- meeec

$ sed "s#$old#$new#" a
bye/how are you?                                      <---- successful!
```